# Selecting observations substring R

Tags: r, string, select, substring

I want to select observations that contain characters which are **not** letters or spaces.

Consider the following vector

```
A=c('C','2A','43?','-B>','Z')
```

The function should return

```
[1] "2A"  "43?" "-B>"
```

I looked at `grep` family and the `stringr`package but could not find what I wanted.

Comment: @CathG Typo. I edited the question.

Comment: Now you completely change the parameters.

Comment: it's not just typo when you ask for the opposite of what you actually want ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the updated output, we match the strings with letters or spaces from start (`^`) to end (`$`), negate `!` and use this as index to return the remaining elements.

```
A[!grepl('^[A-Za-z ]+$', A)]
#[1] "2A"  "43?" "-B>"
```

Or we check for characters that are not LETTERS or spaces (`[^A-Z ]`)

```
grep('[^A-Za-z ]', A, value=TRUE)
#[1] "2A"  "43?" "-B>"
```